# Marking Specific Position on NumberLine Chart Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to plot something but unfourtanetely I couldn't find any tutorial or similar graph that I want. I tried on python and R such as binary timeline, chromomap or timeline graphs but none of them was the right one. Hope you can help me. The desired graph is like;

So, here I have 4 different length, and in this length I want to mark some specific positions.Let say I just want to mark it by using three different colours. For example:

if I detect a position range here let say for Length_1 I want to mark btw 3-7 and I wanna dye with white, I'll dye between 3-7 as white for Length_1.  And maybe other positions with other colours. Same thing with different lenghth (Length_1,Length_2,Length_3,Length_4).

Data for plotting is look like:

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a dataframe for the positions you want to mark including the limits (x coordinates ) for the start and finish positions of each mark and the colours for each mark?

Comment: hey Peter, I dont have data frame positions right now. For now, we may go for imaginary one by making list would be great. Because I'll use list for it probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is updated answer.

Please, read [how to prepare example dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Posting images instead of data isn't really helpful.

As I imagine your data, it must be something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    x = c('K', 'M', 'L', 'N'),   
    y = c(400, 200, 80, 1000),
    m = c(
        '410:419, 200:209', 
        '171:180, 15:24, 39:48', 
        '18:27', 
        '484:493, 200:209, 803:812'
        )
    )
```

With these data in hand, you need to apply some transformations. It is totally the matter of your personal taste how you do it. My approach is as follows:

```
dat <- dat |>
    mutate(m = strsplit(m, ',\\s*')) |>
    unnest(m) |>
    separate(m, c('ymin', 'ymax'), ':', , TRUE) |>
    mutate(
        h  = ymax - ymin,
        y2 = ymin + h / 2,
        ymin = NULL,
        ymax = NULL
    ) |>
    pivot_longer(c('y', 'y2')) |>
    mutate(
        x = factor(x, levels = sort(unique(x), TRUE)),
        h = ifelse(name == 'y', value, h),
        y = ifelse(name == 'y', value / 2, value),
        w = .95,
        f = ifelse(name == 'y', '#4472c4', heat.colors(100, .5)[cut(y + h / 2, 100)])
    ) |>
    select(x, y, h, w, f) |>
    distinct() |>
    arrange(x, desc(h))
```

Your data now, look like this:

```
dat

# # A tibble: 13 × 5
#    x         y     h     w f        
#    <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
# 1  N     500    1000  0.95 #4472c4  
# 2  N     488.      9  0.95 #FFA50080
# 3  N     204.      9  0.95 #FF3E0080
# 4  N     808.      9  0.95 #FFFF3880
# 5  M     100     200  0.95 #4472c4  
# 6  M     176.      9  0.95 #FF340080
# 7  M      19.5     9  0.95 #FF000080
# 8  M      43.5     9  0.95 #FF070080
# 9  L      40      80  0.95 #4472c4  
# 10 L      22.5     9  0.95 #FF000080
# 11 K     200     400  0.95 #4472c4  
# 12 K     414.      9  0.95 #FF8A0080
# 13 K     204.      9  0.95 #FF3E0080
```

Now, after data have been cleaned, it is easy to plot data using `geom_tile()`:

```
dat |>
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, height = h, width = w)) +
    geom_tile(fill = dat$f, show.legend = FALSE) +
    ggtitle('Stack question #6890748♡') +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_void() +
    theme(
        axis.text  = element_text(face = 'italic', size = 12, colour = 'gray50'),
        axis.line.x  = element_line(colour = 'gray10', size = .25),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = 'gray10', size = .25, ),
        axis.ticks.length.x = unit(2, 'points'),
        aspect.ratio = 7 / 16 
    )
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, I just want to ask a thing, i wanna mark special position range, let say btw 9-18 in Length 1 or 27-36 in Length 3. How can I specify that on my data?

Comment: So you don't have data you can plot? My idea is to save the data for marks in `data.frame` which is a part of the data. But you can create a separate `data.frame` with `x` (i.e. `Length`) as a first column, and corresponding `y` column with the coordinate for your mark. You would also probably need third column, let's say `colour` with colour code for the mark.

Comment: I edited and put the example data on question.

Comment: It's late, but you can do something like this:
```markers <- data.frame(
  x = c('K', 'M', 'L', 'N'),
  y = c(400, 200, 80, 1000)
)

markers$z <- list(c(410, 200), c(171, 15, 39), 18, c(484, 200, 803))  
markers$h <- list(c(9, 9), c(9, 9, 9), 9, c(9, 9, 9))```

Comment: I will elaborate on it tomorrow.

Comment: hey, what happened?

Comment: Nothing, I am doing it in my spare time, and I haven't had it yesterday. Should I update the answer? Or add another one?

Comment: you helped a lot, thank you so much! Ill read the link you gave also.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Also read through the code, and try to understand what it does, it will help you with learning.

Comment: Also I missed the + after `ggtitle()`, I updated the answer.

Comment: yeah thank you! if you don't mind i want to ask a question for transformation part. And I'm sorry because of there are a lot of things to consider for this plot I couldnt express myself well. For that part, I want to use just three colour and I want to be able to mark those position intervals with one of this three colour. But I may to choose this position. Like btw 410:419 for K dye with blue or 200:209 for K dye with red or 171:180 for M dye with red etc. Is that possible? Because that part is a bit over me, so I'm not sure I can modify that part. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using `geom_rect`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df_bar <- data.frame(len = paste("Length", 1:4, sep = "_"),
                     xmin = 0,
                     xmax = c(1000, 200, 600, 800),
                     ymin = 1:4,
                     ymax = 1:4 + 0.9,
                     y_lab = 1:4 + 0.5)



df_pos <- data.frame(len = paste("Length", c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), sep = "_"),
                     pos_col = c("w", "w", "r", "r", "g", "g", "w"),
                     pos_start = c(100, 300, 50, 150, 200, 300, 500),
                     pos_end = c(100, 300, 50, 150, 200, 300, 500) + sample(2:20, 7)) 

df_pos <- 
  df_pos %>% 
  left_join(select(df_bar, len, ymin, ymax))

ggplot(df_bar)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), fill = "blue")+
  geom_text(aes(x = xmin, y = y_lab, label = len), hjust = 1.2)+
  geom_rect(data = df_pos, aes(xmin = pos_start, xmax = pos_end, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = pos_col))+
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("w", "r", "g"),
                    values = c("white", "red", "green"))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.15, 0.05)))+
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL,
       fill = NULL)+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>